# Covering an mxn grid

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How many non-overlapping straight line segments of thickness $0<\epsilon<<1$ does it take to cover an mxn square grid? Segments must lie parallell to the lines on the grid.

My thoughts: We need 3 for one node, two more for the neighbour, and so on, but I couldnt find a general formula

Comment: How long are the segments?

Comment: Any length you wish, they can be different

Comment: Are only the nodes to be covered?  Or is it also required to cover edges of the grid?

Comment: @hardmath I presumed the entire area had to be covered?

Comment: edges too, but im interested in the other alternative too

Comment: I don't know what "3 for one Junction" means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson :  Presumably since line segments do not overlap, at a node one either has a segment through the node and two segments on either side that have an "open" endpoint, or four segments meeting at the node but only one of the four including the "closed" endpoint.

Comment: In the case $m=n$, this may be counted by http://oeis.org/A117950 (see the 3rd comment there, the one from Leroy Quet).

Comment: Have you had a look at that link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: Yea, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to cover all edges of an $m \times n$ rectangular grid,
you do not need to cover the interior of the cells.

If you were allowed to overlap the covering strips you would
require just $(m+1)(n+1)$ strips.
(I'm assuming $m \times n$ refers to the number of cells in each direction;
if it refers to the number of nodes then use $mn$ instead.)

But these strips overlap. To convert them to non-overlapping strips
you will have to cut some pieces out of some strips.
Look at the cuts you have to make and how much each cut adds to the total
number of strips.